# Output for adding very Large numbers does not come as expected

Tags: java, string

Given two numbers as input, return the sum of the numbers. Note that the numbers can be very large and hence are provided as Strings.

Note: Without using BigInteger class I have to add them.

```
#Sample Input #1

add("2354725234782357","9999999999999999999999999988888888888")

#Sample Output #1

10000000000000000000002354714123671245

#Sample Input #2

add("1600","213")

#Sample Output #2

1813
```

**MyApproach**

Since the numbers are very large on which I am not getting output.Can anyone guide what I am doing wrong and How to add these numbers.

**Original code:**

```
public String add(String str1, String str2) {
    long number1 = Long.parseLong(str1);
    long number2 = Long.parseLong(str2);
    number1 = number1 + number2;
    return "" + number1;
}
```

Parameters:

```
'2354725234782357' '9999999999999999999999999988888888888'
```

Actual output:

```
null
```

Expected output:

```
10000000000000000000002354714123671245
```

---

**Edit:**

As per MC Emperor suggestions, I got to know how to add numbers very large without using Any BigInteger.

```
Below is the code.

public String add(String a, String b) 
{

     String result = "";
    if(a.length()>b.length())
    {
        int p=a.length()-b.length();
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
         {
          b="0"+b;
         } 
    }
    if(b.length()>a.length())
    {
        int p=b.length()-a.length();
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
         {
           a="0"+a;
         } 
    }
    if(a.length()==b.length()) 
    {    


       int carry = 0;
      for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
      {

         int digitA = a.charAt(i) - 48;
         int digitB = b.charAt(i) - 48;


         int resultingNumber = digitA + digitB + carry;
         if (resultingNumber >= 10) 
         {

            result = (resultingNumber % 10) + result;
             carry = 1;
         }
         else
        {
         result = resultingNumber + result;
         carry = 0;
        }
      }
      if (carry > 0)
     {
       result = carry + result;
     }

   }
   return result;
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `BigDecimal`s?

Comment: How do you print the output ?

Comment: BigInteger or BigDecimal not allowed.

Comment: Have you looked at the range of `long` values? How does that compare with the values you're trying to add together? It sounds like your assignment is basically meant to be "implementing parsing and addition yourself".

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes Sir,It was one of the test case I was not able to pass.I don't even have a clue how to add these numbers..I can't use a different class.I can't split them.

Comment: You can write your own code to do it though. Now you've realized what you're meant to be implementing, I'd suggest going away and trying to work out how addition works using a pen and paper, how to convert a character like '5' into a value 5, and basically trying to do the homework. It'll be fine to ask a question with what you've tried so far, but at the moment this question isn't really suitable.

Comment: remember how as a kid how to add big numbers i.e. from right to left, one number at a time

Comment: Actual output `null` ? When you return `"" + number1` ?? That is not possible with the code above. Either you haven't told us the real actual output or the problem is in code that you haven't posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that a long has by default 64 bits whose 1 is used for sign, so the maximum value is `263-1`, or `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. The assignment is telling you that the numbers can be very large, so I'm guessing that those numbers can exceed the maximum value.

- `Long.parseDouble(String)` doesn't exist, I assume you mean `Long.parseLong(String)`;
- Your code does not output `null` as you stated, it rather emits a `NumberFormattingException`, because the input value is too large.

The assignment is trying to let you build your own mechanism to add two numbers. These are the steps you should take:

1. Take two input strings, say `"134"` and `"258"`. You shouldn't convert them to longs, because of the size limit.
2. Add the two right-most integers, in our case `4` and `8`. If that number is less than 10, you can progress to the next integers. Otherwise, if the number equals or is greater than 10 (in our case, it is `12`), progress to the next two integers starting from the right (`3` and `5`) add 1 to those integers. In our case `3 + 5 + 1 = 9`. If that number is 10 or greater, add 1 to the next integers. In our case, it isn't. Repeat those steps until you have had all digits of the number.

So in code, you have this:

```
public String add(String a, String b) {
    // I assume the strings are equal of length. If they are not, they
    // should be padded with zeroes. Otherwise, you can check if one string
    // has been 'exhaused', avoiding an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

    // The carry is the number which is 'dragged' to the next two integers
    // when it is greater than 9. While adding no more than two numbers, the
    // carry will always be 0 or 1.
    int carry = 0;
    // Our result as a string.
    String result = "";

    // Start at the right-most part the string, because that is
    // the least significant number.
    for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // A string is an array of characters, and the characters '0' till
        // '9' have the ASCII values of 48 till 57. So if we just subtract
        // 48 from the given character, we have the digit the character
        // represents.
        int digitA = a.charAt(i) - 48;
        int digitB = b.charAt(i) - 48;

        // Add both digits and the carry.
        int resultingNumber = digitA + digitB + carry;
        if (resultingNumber >= 10) {
            // We only need the last digit, so we're using the modulo
            // operator, which calculats the remainder. Then we prepend our
            // number to our result string, creating a new result string.
            // You should rather use the StringBuilder class, but for
            // readability, I didn't.
            result = (resultingNumber % 10) + result;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else {
            result = resultingNumber + result;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    // Add the last carry to our result string, if available.
    if (carry > 0) {
        result = carry + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have lots of comments added, to explain the code.

*Note that I have also avoided using StringBuilder, and using ternary if-statements, to improve readability.*

Comment: You made It look its a kid to add numbers.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String fix(String s, int size) {
    int len = size - s.length();
    if (len <= 0) return s;
    return String.format("%0" + len + "d%s", 0, s);
}

public String add(String a, String b) {
    int len = Math.max(a.length(), b.length());
    a = fix(a, len);
    b = fix(b, len);
    StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int sum = carry + a.charAt(i) - '0' + b.charAt(i) - '0';
        r.append((char)(sum % 10 + '0'));
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    if (carry > 0)
        r.append((char)(carry + '0'));
    return r.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is same thing without any BigInteger. Commented Out code for explanation.

```
/**
 * Created by ankur on 10-12-2015.
 *
 * add two very large number without big integer
 */
public class BigStringAddition {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(StringAddition("2354725234782357","9999999999999999999999999988888888888"));

    }

    /*
    function to return the result
     */
    public static String StringAddition(String first, String second){
        StringBuilder bufferRes = new StringBuilder();

        /*
        looping through the index for the break point or carry and adding the result
         */
        for (int index1 = first.length() - 1, index2 = second.length() - 1, carry = 0; index1 >= 0 || index2 >= 0 || carry != 0; index1--, index2--){

            // get the digit from the back and convert it into integer
            int dig1 = index1 < 0 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(first.charAt(index1)));

            int dig2 = index2 < 0 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(second.charAt(index2)));

            // add both the digit and carry

            int resDig = dig1 + dig2 + carry;

            // if the digit is greater than > 9 carry will be 1

            if (resDig > 9){
                carry = 1;
                resDig -= 10;
            }else{
                carry = 0;
            }

            bufferRes.append(resDig);

        }


        return bufferRes.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10000000000000000000002354714123671245.
```

Ideone Link: https://ideone.com/vFiN1I